# Using Mysql IF condition for multiple INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to use condition in Mysql as below

I have 2 tables- **tblPage , tblContent**

The SQL should do something in the following order

1. check if page_name="Home" in tblPage, if false, go to step 2.
2. Insert some values in tblPage, and get the **Last Insert Id**.
3. Insert some values in tbContent with the last Insert Id (of tblPage), and
   get the lastInsertId of its own.
4. Insert some values in tbContent with the lastInsertId (of tbContent), and
   get the lastInsertId of its own.
5. Go on inserting this way.

Step 1 checks to see if any specific value exists in specified column

Step 2 IF the specified `value="Home"` exist,skip step, If Not, insert some values in tblPage and get the last Insert Id

Step 3 insert some values with the lastInsertId of the previous INSERT in the same table

The step may go on this way inserting some other rows in the same table,with each INSERT getting the
**Last Insert Id** for the next

I think its posible with MySql `IFNULL,NULIF,LAST_INSERT_ID` etc, but I cant get it through

I tried with this but the IF condition is still absent.I need to execute the rest of the query if name='home' exists in tblPage

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO 'tblPage' ('id','name','url') VALUES 
(NULL,'index','home/index');
SET @last_id_in_page = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO 'tblcontent' ('id','page_id','parent') VALUES 
(NULL,@last_id_in_page,'home/index');
SET @last_id_in_content = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO 'tblcontent' ('id','page_id','parent') VALUES 
(NULL,@last_id_in_page,@last_id_in_content);
SET @last_id_in_content = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO 'tblcontent' ('id','page_id','parent') VALUES 
(NULL,@last_id_in_page,@last_id_in_content);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last inserted id you can use,

```
$id= mysql_insert_id();
```

after you insert query and  you will get the  last inserted id in table .

Comment: How do I check availability of a value on a column, if false, the rest of the query will be executed